# Trying to crack a code: 055 055 055 055 055 040

Tags: cipher

I am trying this string set of puzzles. The last puzzle to do, began with

055 055 055 055 ...…040 056 055 055 055 055

which translated to:

77777(77777(877 …… 77(87777(87777

But I cannot work out what this code is with all the sevens, eights and brackets. Anyone know?

(see Markdown source of this post for full file)

Comment: In computing, a number with a leading zero is often considered an octal number. In that case, 040, 055 and 056 are the ASCII codes for space, hyphen (dash) and period (dot) respectively. I think you can take it from there. (There are still more steps to the final solution.)

Comment: Please include the source of the puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each spoiler block is progressively closer to the solution.

> As M Oehm pointed out, (040, 055, 056) converts from octal to the character codes for (space, dash, dot). This is obviously Morse code, which I'll not post due to length. Instead, the next spoiler block contains the characters represented in the code.

---

> (Morse code = binary bytes)
> 00110011 01100110 00100000 00110100 00111000 00100000 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110100 01100011 00100000 00110100 01100010 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110100 01100011 00100000 00110101 00110000 00100000 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110100 00110110 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110101 01100001 00100000 00110100 01100011 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110100 00110011 00100000 00110101 00110011 00100000 00110100 01100011 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110100 00110111 00100000 00110100 01100011 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110101 00111001 00100000 00110100 00110110 00100000 00110100 00110001 00100000 00110100 00110100 00100000 00110100 00110100 00100000 00110100 00110001 00100000 00110100 01100110 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110100 01100100 00100000 00110100 00110111 00100000 00110101 00110001 00100000 00110010 00110000 00100000 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110100 01100001 00100000 00110101 00110011

---

> (binary bytes = character codes)
> 51 102 32 52 56 32 53 55 32 52 99 32 52 98 32 50 48 32 52 99 32 53 48 32 53 55 32 52 54 32 50 48 32 53 55 32 53 97 32 52 99 32 50 48 32 53 55 32 52 51 32 53 51 32 52 99 32 50 48 32 52 55 32 52 99 32 50 48 32 53 57 32 52 54 32 52 49 32 52 52 32 52 52 32 52 49 32 52 102 32 50 48 32 52 100 32 52 55 32 53 49 32 50 48 32 53 55 32 52 97 32 53 51

---

> (character string = hexadecimal bytes)
> 3f 48 57 4c 4b 20 4c 50 57 46 20 57 5a 4c 20 57 43 53 4c 20 47 4c 20 59 46 41 44 44 41 4f 20 4d 47 51 20 57 4a 53

---

> (hexadecimal bytes = character codes)
> 63 72 87 76 75 32 76 80 87 70 32 87 90 76 32 87 67 83 76 32 71 76 32 89 70 65 68 68 65 79 32 77 71 81 32 87 74 83

---

> (character string)
> ?HWLK LPWF WZL WCSL GL YFADDAO MGQ WJS

---

> (reverse the string)
> SJW QGM OADDAFY LG LSCW LZW FWPL KLWH?

---

> (after ROT18)
> ARE YOU WILLING TO TAKE THE NEXT STEP?